# How to use volley examples on github

Tags: android, android-volley

I would like to use these examples but I get a lot of errors !

```
The import com.android.volley cannot be resolved
```

Source link:

https://github.com/ogrebgr/android_volley_examples

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clone the Volley Framework and reference it as a library in any projects that you wish to use with it.

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley
```

An example of this can be found [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/android-%E2%80%93-volley-library)